# Oracle query distinct records issue

Tags: oracle10g

I have a table with the following records

```
seqNo   desc  typeID   statusID    GroupSeqNo
1       test    20        30          16
2       test1   21        42          16
3       test2   20        43          17   
4       test3   20        30          17
5       test4   21        42          18
6       test5   20        43          18
```

I am joining this table with couple of other tables to get the typedescription and Statusdescription.

My question is how can I display just one record from each GroupSeqNo? If you look at the above sample records there are 3 records from GroupSeqNo 16, 2 for 17 and 2 for 18.

Below is the query I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SS.GROUPSEQNO,SS.SEQNO,SS.DESC,T.DESC,S.DESC 
FROM STATS SS, DDTYPES T, DDSTATUSES S 
WHERE SS.TYPE_ID=T.TYPE_ID AND SS.STATUS_ID=S.STATUS_ID
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT SS.GROUPSEQNO, SS.DESC,T.DESC,S.DESC FROM STATS SS, DDTYPES T, DDSTATUSES S WHERE SS.TYPE_ID=T.TYPE_ID AND SS.STATUS_ID=S.STATUS_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join a sub query that groups the `STATS` table using `GROUP BY` and selects the `MIN(seqNo)` or `MAX(seqNo)` depending on what you want.

```
SELECT SS.GROUPSEQNO, SS.SEQNO, SS.DESC, T.DESC, S.DESC
FROM STATS SS
  INNER JOIN DDTYPES T ON  SS.TYPE_ID = T.TYPE_ID
  INNER JOIN DDSTATUSES S SS.STATUS_ID = S.STATUS_ID
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(seqNo) MinID
    FROM STATS
    GROUP BY GroupSeqNo
  ) g ON SS.seqNo = g.MinID
```